# Applying a different position for each child of a parent element with a formula?

Tags: css, frontend

I have a parent element with relative positioning and three children elements with absolute positioning. What I wanted to figure out is if there's a way to make each child element have different top/left positioning by their index.

It doesn't have to be strictly this way but what I imagined could be possible would be...

```
.parent-element .child-element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50% - (5 * n);
    left: 50% - (5 * n);
}
```

Where `n` stands for the child's index in the parent element. So the first child would have an index of one, the fifth would have an index of five and so on.

Comment: CSS variables will do this but first can you tell me what the unit of 5*n is to be? % or px or…

Comment: This may be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). There are several other options to have elements overlap (e.g. negative margins, grid layout), that may be more suitable to solve your problem. Try describing the layout you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example.

Each child sets a css variable to its index and this is used in the calculation.

Note I've assumed % is the unit to use as it will be responsive to viewport changes.

```css
.parent-element {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
}

.parent-element .child-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (5% * var(--n)));
  left: calc(50% - (5% * var(--n)));
}

.child-element:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.child-element:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.child-element:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-element">
  <div class="child-element">1</div>
  <div class="child-element">2</div>
  <div class="child-element">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed, probably the optimal solution for the OP but unfortunately, this is not really scalable or can be made dynamic.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, agreed, I normally have to resort to JS to find the number required - and it can be a lot! I wish CSS had some facility where a variable was set automatically for the n in nth-child.